# What are the different terms used to describe a Stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe, stargate-movie

What are all the different terms used to describe the Stargate throughout the various shows?  I know the Jaffa call it the "Chappa'ai". I've also heard "ancestral ring" and "Portal" (including the "Einstein-Rosen Portal"). Any other names?

I know this is a "list" question. But I know the list is small too.

Comment: Gashole. Sun threshold. Neutron doorway…

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(device)) offers a range of alternate names used within the show

> "**Astria Porta**" ([The Ancients/Alterans](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Avalon,_Part_1))
> "**Chappa'ai**" ([The Goa'uld and a host of human slave cultures](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Gods))
> "**Portals**" ([Various Pegasus cultures and the Wraith](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Missing))
> "**Ring of the Gods**" ([Tagreans](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Memento))
> "**Great Ring of Avidan**" ([Tegalusians](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Icon))
> "**Circle of Standing Water**" ([Salish](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Spirits))
> "**Doorway**" ([The Nox](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nox))
> "**Stone Ring**"  ([The Nox](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nox))
> "**Gateway**"  ([The Nox](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nox))
> "**Annulus**" ([K'Tauans](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Sky))
> "**Ring of the Ancestors**" ([Satedan / Athosian](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Rising))
> "**Wraith Well**"  ([M7G-677 inhabitants](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Childhood%27s_End))
> "**Circle of Darkness**"([Medieval planet inhabitants](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Demons))
> "***The Old Orifice***" ([Jack O'Neill](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/10.06_%22200%22_Transcript))
> "**The Ring**" ([Daniel Jackson](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Bad_Guys))
> "**Ancestral Ring**" ([Olesian](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s2/condemned/transcript/))
> "**The Gate**" ([Stargate Movie](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Movie_Transcript))
> "**gate/portal/door of stars**" ([Myers - Stargate Movie](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Movie_Transcript))
> "**Doorway to Heaven**" ([Myers - Stargate Movie](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Stargate:_The_Movie_Transcript))
> “**The Great Circle**” ([Linea - Prisoners (S2,E3)](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Prisoners))
> “**The Great Ring**” ([Camelot Villagers](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/9.20_%22Camelot_Part_2%22_Transcript))

Comment: *No doorway! Denied!*

Comment: I know I've heard the TV characters say things like "Get to the gate!" so it's not just the movie that has said it.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I was merely giving an example. It's not meant to be an exhaustive list of every time someone has called it a thing

Comment: +1 for the Old Orifice from the mouth of O'Neill - I very specifically was checking if it's on the list ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another name I have for the gate:
The "Gate of Magh Mar" - (Revisions - s7e5)

The Ancient and Goa'uld words for the gate:
"Astria Porta"  (in Ancient)
"Chappa'ai"  (in Goa'uld)

The original (true) name for the dialing device in Ancient is "Clavis".

But, I cannot find the Goa'uld word for the dialing device.  (The "DHD" as those from SGC call it.)

Comment: "Clavis" does make sense for the DHD if you think about it: it describes a thing with which to open another thing: a "Key"